# cassandra cluster not ring

Tags: cassandra

I'm setting up cassandra cluster.I made the configuration changes(adding seeds). When I ring that cluster, its showing only one node. bit actually 2 nodes on my cluster. what change should be done. 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

As well as adding seeds, you need to configure the listen_address for your nodes so they aren't just listening on localhost (the same goes for the rpc_address). You need to enable auto-bootstrap for your new node, or set its token manually so that it takes on a portion of the keyspace from the original node.

See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MultinodeCluster for details.

Answer (score 4):

If you're setting up the cluster using virtual machines, this is a common scenario.  Here's why:  http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#cloned

Even if this isn't your case, as a solution, you can use the nodetool move command to re-assign the token space.
For Example, on a 4 node cluster:

```
nodetool -h NodeA move 0
nodetool -h NodeB move 42535295865117307932921825928971026431
nodetool -h NodeC move 85070591730234615865843651857942052863
nodetool -h NodeD move 127605887595351923798765477786913079295
```